# not able to differ the contains of the two different fragments

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm developing android screen for showing 2 different dashboard using `tablayout` & `viewpager` but only one screen shown at two different tabs(i.e. on `MyDashboard` & `TeamDashboard`).Please check my code.I'm new to android development.

I tried to use `viewpager` with `pageradapter` for swipe the screen.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int position;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"MyDashboard", "Team` `Dashboard"};

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        //        MyDashboard_Fragment dashboard_fragment=new `MyDashboard_Fragment();
        //        TeamDashboard_Fragment dashboard_fragment1=new `TeamDashboard_Fragment();
        //        position = position + 1;
        //        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        //        bundle.putString("message","Fragment :" +position);
        //        dashboard_fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        //        return dashboard_fragment;

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new MyDashboard_Fragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new TeamDashboard_Fragment();
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please describe your problem, what issue are you getting?

Comment: i want to show two different screens on section wise in tabbed layout

Comment: but what issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because you are not assigning the new value to position variable before use it, please update your code like bellow

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int position;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"MyDashboard", "Team` `Dashboard"};

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        //        MyDashboard_Fragment dashboard_fragment=new `MyDashboard_Fragment();
        //        TeamDashboard_Fragment dashboard_fragment1=new `TeamDashboard_Fragment();
        //        position = position + 1;
        //        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        //        bundle.putString("message","Fragment :" +position);
        //        dashboard_fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        //        return dashboard_fragment;
        position=i;
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new MyDashboard_Fragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new TeamDashboard_Fragment();
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your welcome, When you are debugging any code first check line by line code and your logic.